# Where can I publish my biography online for free where it will be preserved?

Tags: publishing, resources, websites

I'm a strictly-amateur author.  I've written my autobiography.

I don't want to be paid but I feel it has value and would like it preserved online in some fashion for posterity.

How can I go about this?  I can't pay anything substantial for the service.

Answer (score 2):

Look up Wordpress. My aunt published a book on her work as a translator. With her permission, I made a WP version of the book; clicking on Next brought up the next chapter of the book. That meant adding in the book chapters backwards so the first pages would appear first. It also meant I could add maps and color photos that were pertinent to the story in the chapters they appear.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of printing and web publishing possibilities.  That's the easy bit.

How it might be available to people in 100 years time is the tricky part.  Ask yourself the question "Who cares?"  Family?  Professional body?  Local historians?  Approach these and ask if they're interested in *all or part*. For example a local museum might be interested in describing arts and crafts of a rapidly fading age but won't want to know about your childhood holidays hiking up Mt. Everest.  So you collaborate with them to produce something for them and their audience.  Trudging through the snow drifts to get supplies perhaps but your struggle with alcoholism not so much.

Practical advice:

- Electronic copies are best to start with.   It's easier to adapt.
- Make sure somebody has a printed copy to collect dust on their shelf.
- Try enriching your story with photographs, newspaper cuttings etc.
- Try to make it interesting for an audience.  As above you may find multiple, disparate, audiences.

Comment: Get it published with an ISBN, then donate a copy to the Library of Congress. YMMV and not all works are accepted. https://ask.loc.gov/faq/299768